# Why does this for loop have no effect? (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a variable that contains a city, or city plus punctuation and then Post Code. I am using a statement to remove punctuation (and other stray) characters. It looks like this:

```
for c in "!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>,.":
    jobLocationCleaned = string.replace(jobLocationUnclean, c, "")
jobLocation = jobLocationCleaned

# Add to list
params.append(jobLocation)
print(jobLocation)
```

However, when using Debug I can see the code step through and do the job it is supposed to yet when it comes to the `print` statement it prints the address before it was cleaned, i.e. the `for` loop has no effect.

Why is this?

Comment: Because your title is bad.

Comment: What are the values of `jobLocationUnclean`?

Comment: Note: you shouldn't need to say `string.replace(variable,..` just do `variable.replace(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each iteration you are doing the replacement on `jobLocationUnclean` but assigning the result to `jobLocationClean`.  Since you use the same unclean starting point on each iteration only the last iteration will have any affect on the result.  Try changing your code to the following:

```
jobLocation = jobLocationUnclean
for c in "!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>,.":
    jobLocation = jobLocation.replace(c, "")

params.append(jobLocation)
print(jobLocation)
```

Note that I also made two other minor modifications, I just use `jobLocation` and got rid of `jobLocationClean` because it is unnecessary, and instead of `string.replace(jobLocation, c, "")` I used `jobLocation.replace(c, "")`.  This is the recommended way to call string functions, directly on the object rather than from the string module.

Answer (score 9):

In the loop, you never use the result of previous iteration and use the original string instead. This is the root of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `regex` for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> from string import punctuation as punc
>>> strs = "Abc*@ddf%^sad#"
>>> re.sub(r'[{}]'.format(punc),'',strs)
'Abcddfsad'
```

Fixing your code:

```
>>> jobLocationUnclean = 'Abc*@ddf%sad#'
>>> for c in "!@#%&*()[]{}/?<>,.":
        #re-assign the new string to the `jobLocationUnclean`
        jobLocationUnclean = jobLocationUnclean.replace(c, "")
>>> jobLocationUnclean
'Abcddfsad'
```

Why your code failed?

In your code you are looping through those punctuations and assigning a 
replaced value of `jobLocationUnclean` to `jobLocationCleaned`, though note that
strings are immutable in python so that `replace(jobLocationUnclean, c, "")` 
operation doesn't changes the original `jobLocationUnclean` at all. So,in each iteration you replaces a given punctuation and assign the new string to `jobLocationCleaned`.
Any operation on a string always returns a new string.

```
>>> strs = "foo"
>>> strs.replace('f','i')
'ioo'
>>> strs  #original foo is still un-changed
'foo'
```

So in the end your code actually replaced only the `.` character in the string(`jobLocationUnclean`) and assigned that to `jobLocationCleaned`.